# Spurious ImportErrors (with modules importing submodules?)

Tags: python, django, import, importerror

I have a problem that I don't really know where to begin solving. Maybe it'll ring someone's bell.

**TLDR:** a Django app crashes and upon restart it runs but fails to import some modules. Upon another restart, all is fine again.

The whole story:

Different applications (we're up to three right now) on different Python (2.5.x, 2.6.x and 2.6.x) and Django versions (1.1.0, 1.2.5 and 1.3.0, respectively) occasionally exhibit spurious ImportErrors. For example, one of these apps started to fail every request by throwing an ImportError inside:

```
from django.contrib.gis.maps.google import GMarker, GEvent
```

We collected `strace` output and the relevant chunk is below (absolute path replaced with DIR for brevity and protecting the guilty).

```
stat64("DIR/django/contrib/gis/maps/google/GMarker", 0xf699ce3c) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("DIR/django/contrib/gis/maps/google/GMarker.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("DIR/django/contrib/gis/maps/google/GMarkermodule.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("DIR/django/contrib/gis/maps/google/GMarker.py", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("DIR/django/contrib/gis/maps/google/GMarker.pyc", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

(and once again the same thing s/GMarker/GEvent/)

After restarting the process everything runs smoothly, also running:

```
python -c 'from django.contrib.gis.maps.google import GMarker'
```

produces no errors.

The GMarker and GEvent classes are actually defined in `django.contrib.gis.maps.google.overlays` and imported in `...maps/google/__init__.py`:

```
from django.contrib.gis.maps.google.gmap import GoogleMap, GoogleMapSet
from django.contrib.gis.maps.google.overlays import GEvent, GIcon, GMarker, GPolygon, GPolyline
from django.contrib.gis.maps.google.zoom import GoogleZoom
```

so it's fully expected that loading GMarker.py et al. will fail. It seems that Python has somehow forgotten about `__init__.py` and its namespace.

The apps are relatively high-traffic and it is conceivable (though not certain) that they might have exceeded their VM limits and recovered almost-gracefully. Also, at least in two cases the app had earlier problems leading to a crash -- SIGSEGV in one case, and err... something else in the other). A single app restart caused it to throw ImportErrors around, and another one made it behave again. Corrupted .py[c]? Timestamps are ancient.

All these apps are running on flup the wsgi-to-fastcgi server.

Each of these apps failed once so far (in completely different modules, two cases of `__init__.py` "forgotten" but I cannot find the third error ATM) so I cannot tell whether the modules are somehow meaningful.

Any and all pointers and ideas appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify how you are managing the multiple different Python and Django versions - is this on different systems or all on the same, with virtualenv or some other hack to have them running in parallel?

Comment: Completely unrelated systems (different physical machines, different DCs). The base image is the same so e.g. all the Python versions are installed everywhere. The steady state though is everything working fine (sys.path is correct etc.). Restarting the app with 100% identical environment "fixes" whatever the problem was.

Comment: These are not my applications to upgrade. I'm stuck with whatever they're using.

Comment: Are you sure that your webserver configuration doesn't use treads? Do you see `'wsgi.multithread': False` in your reports? Otherwise the server configuration (used apache?, module, options, flup version etc.) can more important than your applications. Try also to think about two FAQs: [I have problem with flup... and Calling WSGIServer.run from an...](http://trac.saddi.com/flup/wiki/FlupFaq#Ihaveproblemswithflupanddynamicwebserver-launchedFastCGIapplications)

Answer (score 1):

Actually your strace line does not help a bit; those accesses did not result in the module being imported.

There might be multiple reasons for such import errors:

1. someone modifies sys.path and that is not within the module path anymore
2. a cyclical import in those modules, that is triggered by you importing from another module first!
3. you have site conflict (yep, had that kind of), same module being loaded from different site packages locations
4. you have a module in the search path conflicting with an other module somewhere, or with a system module.

If you would paste the SECOND set of strace lines, we would be closer to solution?

### Update

For 2. I mean that if you have 2 files with the following structure

foo.py/**init**.py:

```
from bar import baz
```

bar.py/**init**.py:

```
import foo
def baz():
     pass
```

snafu.py:

```
import bar
import foo
```

ok.py:

```
import foo
import snafu
```

Run python snafu.py and you get a crash and similar strace output, run python ok.py and everything works.

Comment: Well, the problem has not returned for some time and it's rather low priority for me now. What exactly do you mean by the second set?

All the things you mention would cause the app not to work completely, not fail to restart _once_ after a crash, right?

Comment: not necessarily true, except for maybe 4. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I experimented with the cyclical import hypothesis of mine, making packages foo and bar, with the above contents; If I import bar first, I get strace output when python is trying to look for baz.py, baz.so etc... So that is what I am leaning towards now.

Answer (score 0):

The strace output seems suspicious to me:

```
DIR/django/contrib/gis/...
```

I am wondering about this `DIR` part. Is it possible you misstyped the PYTHONPATH variable somewhere, using `DIR`instead of `$DIR`?

Comment: No, I replaced the full path with "DIR" for brevity mostly while preparing this post. $PYTHONPATH is correct, as seen after application restart.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to wrap the import with a try... except ImportError and add a code doing something like that (anything that logs, instead of print, will do)

```
import sys
print sys.modules["django.contrib.gis.maps.google"]
print dir(sys.modules["django.contrib.gis.maps.google"])
```

This should let you understand what's happening.